# Machine Learning to discover duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Why doesn't Stack Overflow implement an algorithm able to detect the % of similarity in questions being asked and if that percentage is above a certain threshold the user is denied posting? Is it in progress? Any reason preventing that feature from being integrated?

While fully understand the complexity of this problem, I think it is possible to develop such a system unless there is a common belief that this feature isn't worth the effort!

Comment: Easier said than done. If you think you can do it, speak up and SE will hire you. :)

Comment: I fully understand the underlying complexity behind implementing such a feature, but i think the ROI is wortwhile isn't it? I do believe it's a solvable problem even if the accuracy rate is not optimal.

Comment: @BassemDy: I don't think you do understand the complexity behind implementing it, because if it were easy to do this _accurately_, someone besides search engines would have done it.

Comment: Let's just say, I've had my fair share of tinkering in NLP, Sentiment analysis and Classifiers to know that this is entirely feasible. While it's not a weekend job, it's not an open problem also. My knowledge of the Machine Learning field is quite irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I really don't have an exact answer to your question, but I do tend to think it's not worth implementing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, this does happen to generate the "Related" and the "Questions that may already have your answer" lists, to provide suggestions of possible duplicates. But I'm fairly confident that they'll stay just that: suggestions, rather than a hard "you can't post this" restriction.

You agree that the accuracy might not be optimal, but I think you underestimate how annoying false positives would be. Imagine how frustrating it would be to write a question, but have the system tell you it was a duplicate of a question that you knew it wasn't. (There are many pairs of questions that use similar words, but are asking something completely different).

You'd be forced to resort to changing words in the title and description with the goal of making it less similar to the previous question. This both frustrates the user and leads to a lower quality question.

Comment: Yep. The high false positive rate is gonna annoy a lot of legitimate users.

Comment: Agreed. If real intelligence (ok, "intelligence" might be a stretch, but real people at least) frequently make false positive duplicate identifications, how can we expect an artificial intelligence to do it properly?

Comment: Improving the accuracy of the "Related" and "Questions like this" lists would be a welcome first step. Ditto for search. I often find myself reverting to Google to find relevant content on SO rather than relying on the site's own result lists. I second the call for more work in this area.

Comment: @tripleee, I second that. Before posting a question, I'll always google first, and only then (if I don't find a match) will I enter it in SO and look the suggestions. Google almost always gives better matches than the SO suggestions, and SO search is probably based on a similar index.

Answer (score 4):

You must have not seen the [Stack Exchange Machine Learning Contest](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-machine-learning-contest/) that they ran last year. In an attempt to detect questions that might be problematic for the site, they published a dataset of closed and open questions and invited people to develop means of determining the likelihood that a given question would be closed.

While not specifically applied to duplicates, this was a broader initiative to detect questions that might not be appropriate here and somehow aid in the moderation of these. The way this would be integrated into the system isn't disclosed.

Comment: I had missed that - thanks for the info (and providing the link).

Comment: Yep it seems I have missed it :) Thanks for sharing the link. This is the most interesting and constructive answer I received for this question, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

This would be a bad idea.

There are sometimes subtle (and sometimes not so subtle) differences that make what appears to be a duplicate actually not one, and humans sometimes have difficulty making that distinction.

I myself have voted to close something that appeared to be a duplicate, even when reading both questions, and then had someone else bring to my attention that it in fact wasn't one because of something I've missed. (I've then left a comment acknowledging my mistake to let others know not to downvote as a result, and flagged it as "other" for the mods to let them know of my error.) I've seen this happen with others as well, and sometimes been the one letting them know of the differences.

If actual people (who have a much more thorough understanding of content and context) sometimes can't make the distinction, allowing an AI to decide and "deny posting" would be a severe reduction in the usability of SE sites. (Sometimes it's annoying already when you try to edit a post with a poor subject and can't, because the site's current duplicate checking logic says it already exists, and then you realize that's why the original poster phrased it poorly the way they did in the first place - to get the question here in the first place.)

Remember [IBM's Watson on Jeopardy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson_%28computer%29)? It eventually won, but frequently had some very humorous lapses in comprehension that made it ridiculously wrong, and it was *specifically* designed to answer Jeopardy questions at a quite considerable cost for that AI (text from linked article, but **emphasis mine**):

> Watson is made up of a cluster of **ninety IBM Power 750 servers (plus additional I/O, network and cluster controller nodes in 10 racks) with a total of 2880 POWER7 processor cores and 16 Terabytes of RAM**. Each Power 750 server uses a 3.5 GHz POWER7 eight core processor, with four threads per core. The POWER7 processor's massively parallel processing capability is an ideal match for Watson's IBM DeepQA software which is embarrassingly parallel (that is a workload that is easily split up into multiple parallel tasks).[16]
>
> According to John Rennie, Watson can process 500 gigabytes, the equivalent of a million books, per second.[17] IBM's master inventor and senior consultant Tony Pearson **estimated Watson's hardware cost at about $3 million[18] and with 80 TeraFLOPs would be placed 94th on the Top 500 Supercomputers list.[19]**

With due respect to SE, that seems like a very large investment financially just in the hardware (and the cost of developing the software isn't included in the above - that's just the hardware investment for that TV appearance) just to avoid the occasional duplicate question that gets posted. The moderators and users at SE work for considerably less. (Well, I do anyway - who knows what hidden secrets lie behind those little diamonds?)

Comment: I observe that Canonical's (and thus Ubuntu's) [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net/) has made significant improvements in this area, presumably with a significantly smaller investment, and (to the best of my knowledge) the results are published as open source. Their duplicate bug report check used to be ridiculously poor (often failing the laugh/cry test; in other words, similar to SO's search performance now), but since several years back, it has saved me from posting duplicate bug reports on numerous occasions. Unfortunately, I can't tell you exactly what they did.

Comment: ... The problem areas are quite similar, so I would assume that a comparable accuracy would be achievable on SO, and quite possibly most of the SE sites.

Comment: In fact, I would speculate that they just created smarter indices, rather than developed significant new search logic. The change happened basically overnight, suggesting that they just switched to a better (perhaps more focused?) feature model, whereas a significant software development effort would have shown (a) iterative improvement and (b) pompous fanfares from the PR unit.